# Acesso Negado ao inserir valor no registro do windows por Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Na tentativa de criar uma função que inserisse um valor em uma chave do registro do windows, me deparei com um erro. Utilizo Windows 8 e Python 3.5. A função é a seguinte:

```
def inserir1(nome,path):
    import winreg
    key=winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,'Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run')
    winreg.SetValueEx(key,nome,0,winreg.REG_SZ,path)
    key.Close()

inserirchave('teste','C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\teste.txt')
```

O erro que esse script gera é o seguinte:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Inserir Chave.py", line 16, in <module>
    inserir1(nome,path)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Inserir Chave.py", line 8, in inserir1
    winreg.SetValueEx(key,nome,0,winreg.REG_SZ,path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado
```

Logo, tentei executar o script com privilégios de administrador, porém sem êxito, já que o mesmo erro ocorreu mesmo com tais privilégios. Tentei fazer manualmente pelo regedit e não houve problema algum. Como eu posso conseguir a permissão para executar esse script?

Comment: Como você fez o processo de executar em modo Adm? Abriu o CMD com o direito e escolheu "Executar como Administrador"?

Comment: Fiz de duas maneiras: abri o cmd como administrador através do clique com botão direito do Mouse e digitei python inserirchave.py; a outra maneira foi abrindo o próprio python como administrador, também pelo botão direito (nesse caso, digitei linha por linha)

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
def inserir1(nome,path):
  key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
  key = CreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal)
  SetValueEx(key, nome, 0, REG_SZ, path)
  CloseKey(key)

inserir1('teste','C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\teste.txt')
```

Comment: Edit: Remover a linha `key = CreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal)`

Comment: tentei fazer o que me propôs, e inicialmente deu errado. Porém, tentei executar como administrador e aparentemente tinha dado certo, pois nenhum erro apareceu. Contudo, o valor teste.txt não apareceu na chave Run, ou seja, não deu erro mas também não funcionou. Se tiveres mais alguma ideia, agradeço.

Comment: Vou tentar trabalhar em uma no que você sugeriu, enquanto isso, @carlos.